# Problem with reflection in Unit/Integration tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reflection

I´m dynamically creating an instance of a class with reflection and this works fine, except when trying to do this through unit testing - I´m using the MS testing framework.

I get the familiar error of: "Could not load file or assembly 'Assy' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified"

I have copied the dll into the bin\debug bin of the Unit test project - is this not the correct place to put it?

```
string assyName = "Go.Data.SqlServer";
string typeName = "GoMolaMola.Data.SqlServer.DataProviderFactory";

Assembly assy = Assembly.Load( assyName );
object o = assy.CreateInstance( typeName );
```

Any ideas? I'm new to unit testing and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `bin/Debug` folder is not where the unit tests run. Visual Studio will copy the output of your unit test compilation to a `TestResults` folder (typically keeping the last five test runs, each with a timestamp embedded in the folder name) and run the unit tests there.

If you want the .DLL in that folder, either create a reference to the .DLL from your test project, or use the [DeploymentItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.webtesting.deploymentitemattribute.aspx) attribute to make sure the item is copied to the test directory.

Comment: You are right, it's not run from the bin folder.
I added a reference from the test project and that took care of that!
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem too and none of the above answer worked for me :(
1. Adding reference to project doesn't work for me
2. Adding the DeploymentItem attribute also doesn't work
3. Adding the Post-Build command is also not possible in this case as Unit test engine is creating a new out directory each time with time stamp....and its searching that assembly in this new directory.

but I managed to solve this by enabling deployment and adding the specified file in Local Test Setting -->Deployment

Answer (score 0):

For cases like this, when loading the DLL dynamically is needed from the Unit Testing, I have a post-build event that copies the DLL to that directory. I'd love to know if there's another way to do it. That was the only way that worked for me :(

To edit a **Post-Build**, right-click over the project, go to **Build events**, and place the copy, like this, in the Post-Build event command line:

```
copy $(TargetPath) "$(SolutionDir)yourDir\$(TargetFileName)"
```